# Removing points and small lines in opencv

Tags: opencv, lines

Is there any function or algorithm to remove points and small/short lines from the image. I have made a metric map for robot. I have used algorithm to make a skeleton from the image. What I need is, to remove small/short lines and point to get smooth lines- see the [picture](http://www.ulozisko.sk/obrazky/608556/pic.png). I am new in opencv, so maybe it is simple problem.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

To make skeleton I use this code

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

cv::Mat img = cv::imread("test4.png", 0);

cv::Mat skel(img.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

cv::Mat temp(img.size(), CV_8UC1);

cv::Mat sub_mat = Mat::ones(img.size(), img.type())*255;

cv::Mat eroded;

cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, 

cv::Size(3, 3));

cv::subtract(sub_mat, img, img);


bool done;      
do
{
  cv::erode(img, eroded, element);
  cv::dilate(eroded, temp, element); // temp = open(img)
  cv::subtract(img, temp, temp);
  cv::bitwise_or(skel, temp, skel);
  eroded.copyTo(img);

  done = (cv::countNonZero(img) == 0);
} while (!done);


cv::subtract(sub_mat, skel, skel);

cv:imwrite("skelet.png",skel);

cv::imshow("Skeleton", skel);

cv::waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to try some of the filters on image. I guess median will be a good choice to start with.

Comment: Well, I have used then Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm/skeletonization :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove points and noise in general, the simplest way is to implement a Median filter (a filter based on the median of the pixel's neighbourhood).

Here is en example on how to program it in c:

```
    Mat median(Mat in)
{
    int sizeW = 3;//Neighborhood size
    int offset = sizeW/2; //external border of the image
    if(in.channels()==3) cvtColor(in,in,CV_BGR2GRAY,1);
    in.convertTo(in, CV_8UC1);

    //Init
    int x,y,i,j,k;
    uchar temp;
    uchar median[9] = {0};// the size of this matrix = sizeW²
    int nRows = in.rows;
    int nCols = in.cols;
    Mat out = Mat::zeros(nRows-2*offset, nCols-2*offset, CV_8UC1 );


    //Processing
    for(x=offset; x<nRows-offset; x++)
        for(y=offset; y<nCols-offset; y++)
    {
        //Median
        for(i=(-sizeW/2); i<=sizeW/2; i++)
            for(j=(-sizeW/2); j<=sizeW/2; j++)
                median[(i+sizeW/2)*sizeW + (j+sizeW/2)] = in.at<uchar>(x+i,y+j);

        //Sort the median array
        for(int z=0; z<sizeW*sizeW; z++)
            for(k=1; k<sizeW*sizeW; k++){
                if(median[k-1]>median[k]){
                    temp = median[k-1];
                    median[k-1] = median[k];
                    median[k] = temp;
                }
            }
        out.at<uchar>(x-offset,y-offset) = median[(sizeW*sizeW/2)+1];
    }// for all pixels      

    return out; 
}
```

You should try with the neighbourhood size = 3.